# Zkemkeeper OnattTransactionex listener to listen multiple devices

Tags: vb.net

I used axCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx(string EnrollNumber, int IsInValid, int AttState, int VerifyMethod, int Year, int Month, int Day, int Hour, int Minute, int Second, int WorkCode) to insert data into db but I could not find device ID. I need to know which machine triggered this event.

I have done via an array of axCZKEM, Events are working fine but unable to get ip of the triggered machine

```
    For i = 0 To LsvMachines.Items.Count - 1
        If LsvMachines.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text = "Connected" Then
            axCZKEMiu(Val(LsvMachines.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text)).Disconnect()
            RemoveHandler axCZKEMiu(Val(LsvMachines.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text)).OnAttTransactionEx, AddressOf AxCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx
            bIsConnected = False
            LsvMachines.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text = "Connect"
        Else
            ReDim Preserve axCZKEMiu(mIndex)
            axCZKEMiu(mIndex) = New zkemkeeper.CZKEM
            bIsConnected = axCZKEMiu(mIndex).Connect_Net(LsvMachines.Items(i).Text, 4370) 'IP , Port

            If bIsConnected = True Then
                LsvMachines.Items(i).SubItems(2).Text = "Connected"
                LsvMachines.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text = mIndex
                If axCZKEMiu(mIndex).RegEvent(1, 65535) = True Then
                    'Here you can register the realtime events that you want to be triggered(the parameters 65535 means registering all)
                    AddHandler axCZKEMiu(mIndex).OnAttTransactionEx, AddressOf AxCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx
                End If
                mIndex = mIndex + 1
                bIsConnected = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

```
#Region "RealTime Events"

    Private Sub AxCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx(ByVal sEnrollNumber As String, ByVal iIsInValid As Integer, ByVal iAttState As Integer, ByVal iVerifyMethod As Integer, _
                      ByVal iYear As Integer, ByVal iMonth As Integer, ByVal iDay As Integer, ByVal iHour As Integer, ByVal iMinute As Integer, ByVal iSecond As Integer, ByVal iWorkCode As Integer)

       'I want to get ip address of triggered machine before saving 

    End Sub

#End Region
```

Comment: Is this code running on the machine with the database? Which database program is it?

Comment: i am working with database, here ip address of machines coming from a listview control (LsvMachines) filled from database already. (MS SQL & vb.net)

Answer (score 0):

You can't define machine ID by IP connection solution, just assign it number 1. But you can use IP address to identify a machine.

```
namespace XXXXX
{
    internal class DeviceInfo
    {
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }
        public string MachineNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper class that hold both the axCZKEM object and its related information, i.e. IP Address, DeviceNo etc..
then ,  create AxCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx as a method of that class.
after, you create a list of objects of that class and you are ready to go.

```
        Public Class FingerPrintDevice
        Public DeviceNo As Integer, DeviceIPAddress As String, DevicePortNo As Integer, IsDeviceConnected As Boolean = False
        Public FDevice As New zkemkeeper.CZKEM
        Public Sub New(IPAddress As String, PortNo As Integer, iMachineNumber As Integer)
            DeviceIPAddress = IPAddress
            DevicePortNo = PortNo
            DeviceNo = iMachineNumber
            Initiate()
        End Sub
        Sub Initiate()
            IsDeviceConnected = FDevice.Connect_Net(DeviceIPAddress, DevicePortNo)
            If IsDeviceConnected = True Then
                
                If FDevice.RegEvent(DeviceNo, 65535) Then 
                    AddHandler FDevice.OnAttTransactionEx, AddressOf AxCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
        Private Sub AxCZKEM1_OnAttTransactionEx(ByVal sEnrollNumber As String, ByVal iIsInValid As Integer, ByVal iAttState As Integer, ByVal iVerifyMethod As Integer,
                         ByVal iYear As Integer, ByVal iMonth As Integer, ByVal iDay As Integer, ByVal iHour As Integer, ByVal iMinute As Integer, ByVal iSecond As Integer, ByVal iWorkCode As Integer)

'your Desired Code Here

    end Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It seems that indentation is off in the first line and near the end